# Multiple onload conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

Hi there… I've run into a problem using the jQuery thumbnail scroller. It clashes with Fancybox and another script I've been using based on the onload event. I found this function which enables multiple onload events to fire by simon wilson:

---

```
function func1() {
  alert("This is the first.");
}
function func2() {
  alert("This is the second.");
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}
addLoadEvent(func1);
addLoadEvent(func2);
addLoadEvent(function() {

I WANT TO INSERT THE FOLLOWING JQUERY FUNCTION HERE

})
```

---

My problem now is getting the 3rd function to work correctly. It's a syntax problem.

Here is the jQuery I want to insert:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
window.onload=function(){ 
    $("#tS3").thumbnailScroller({ 
        scrollerType:"hoverPrecise", 
        scrollerOrientation:"vertical", 
        scrollSpeed:2, 
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
        scrollEasingAmount:800, 
        acceleration:4, 
        scrollSpeed:800, 
        noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
        autoScrolling:0, 
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
        autoScrollingDelay:500 
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function func1() {
  alert("This is the first.");
}
function func2() {
  alert("This is the second.");
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}
addLoadEvent(func1);
addLoadEvent(func2);
addLoadEvent(function() {
    $("#tS3").thumbnailScroller({ 
        scrollerType:"hoverPrecise", 
            scrollerOrientation:"vertical", 
            scrollSpeed:2, 
            scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
            scrollEasingAmount:800, 
            acceleration:4, 
            scrollSpeed:800, 
            noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
            autoScrolling:0, 
            autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
            autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
            autoScrollingDelay:500 
        });
})
```

Your problem was that the function that you were trying to add was specifically overriding `window.onload` with its own function, rather than appending itself like it is meant to.

Comment: Thanks Blair... It works for the first two functions, but still don't fire the third function. It has something to do with the jQuery no-conflict rule. Here is the entire contents of the script that I way to run third:

Comment: *Please see the initial question, I have added the jQuery.noConflict(); line above the function that I need to insert!

Comment: Fixed. Thanks Blair... I simply changed the order and removed the conflicting plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do this? Why do you need to queue the `onload` handlers like that? And since you are using jQuery already, why are using native handlers already?

```
function func1() { ... }
function func2() { ... }
function thumbScroller() {
$("#tS3").thumbnailScroller({ 
        scrollerType:"hoverPrecise", 
        scrollerOrientation:"vertical", 
        scrollSpeed:2, 
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
        scrollEasingAmount:800, 
        acceleration:4, 
        scrollSpeed:800, 
        noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
        autoScrolling:0, 
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
        autoScrollingDelay:500 
    });
}
```

Now call them all collectively

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    func1();
    func2();
    thumbScroller();
});
```